# ASP.NET Master-Content-IFRAME to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I have an ASP.NET web application that has a structure like MasterPage --> ContentPage--> Two IFRAMES which point to two different web pages.

Reports is a ContentPage that has two iframes and we use a customized version of jquery splitter to get the split screen view.

Now we are thinking of migrating this application to MVC with similar split screen GUI.

I have been reading about MVC to till now I have not got any idea on how to implement this.

Can some one please guide me on how this can be achieved and most preferably using Razor View Engine (if possible)

Following is the current applications ASP.NET ContentPage code. I want to put it in a View and iframe should point to another View...

```
<div id="mainSplitter">
        <div style="-ms-overflow-y: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: hidden; -ms-overflow-x: hidden;">
            <iframe id="infoPane" src="../Reports/ReportsInfo.aspx" style="border-bottom: 0PX; border-left: 0PX; border-top: 0PX; border-right: 0PX" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div style="-ms-overflow-y: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: hidden; -ms-overflow-x: hidden;">
            <iframe id="searchPane" src="" style="border-bottom: 0PX;
                border-left: 0PX; border-top: 0PX; border-right: 0PX" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it, all you need to do is to add a HtmlHelper

```
@Url.Action("actionMethod", "Controller")
```

to the src attribute of the iframe.

This can be done inline or using jquery

```
$("#infopane").attr("src", '@Url.Action("ReportInfo", "Report")')
```